# Django giving error "The current path, item/14/add_to_cart1/, didn't match any of these."

Tags: django

I'm trying to add add-to-cart functionality in my django product.First I have list view of Items then I have detail view then I'm adding Items according to the Item-id to the cart.My **urls.py** is as follows:

```
    url('logout/', views.logout, name="logout"),
    url('^contact$', views.contact, name='contact'),
    url('^signup', views.signup, name="signup"),
    # url('^index$', views.index, name = 'index'),
    url('^about$', views.about, name='about'),
    url('^demo', views.demo, name='demo'),
    url('^payment', views.payment, name='payment'),
    url('logout', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),

    path('detail', views.detai, name='detai'),
    url('^$', views.home,name = 'home'),
    re_path('^item/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ItemDetail.as_view(), name='item'),
    path('^add/<int:id>', views.add_to_cart1, name="add_to_cart1"),
```

***this is my views.py***

```
def add_to_cart1(request, id):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, id=id)
    order_item, created = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(
        item=item,
        user=request.user,

    )
    order_qs = CartItem.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        if order.items.filter(item = item).exists():
            order_item.quantity += 1
            order_item.save()
            messages.info(request, "Item qty was updated.")
            return redirect("core:order-summary")
        else:
            order.items.add(order_item)
            messages.info(request, "Item was added to your cart.")
            return redirect("core:order-summary")
    else:

        order = CartItem.objects.create(
            user=request.user,  )
        order.items.add(order_item)
        messages.info(request, "Item was added to your cart.")
    return render(request,"index.html")
```

this the error I'm getting:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLtDx.png)

After adding slash"/" `i.e. <a href="/add/<item-id>/">`in the template, getting error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aK8H2.png)

this is item_detail.html

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<section class="w3l-specification-6">
    <!-- /specification-6-->
    <div class="specification-6-mian py-5">
      <div class="container py-lg-5">
        <div class="row story-6-grids text-left">

          <div class="col-lg-5 story-gd">
            <img src="{{object.image.url}}" class="img-fluid" alt="/">
            <a href="/add/{{object.id}}/">
                <button class="top_transmitv_cart" type="submit" name="submit" value="" >
                                    Add to Cart
                                    <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></span>
            </a>                    </button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-7 story-gd pl-lg-4">
            <h3 class="hny-title"><span>{{object.title}}</span></h3>


            <div class="row story-info-content mt-md-5 mt-4">

              <div class="col-md-12 story-info">
                <h5> <a href="#">Product Description</a></h5>
                <p>{{object.description}}</p>
                <br>

              </div>
              <div class="col-md-12 story-info">
                <h5> <a href="#">Price</a></h5>
                <span class="price"><del>&#x20b9;{{object.discount_price}}</del>&#x20b9;{{object.price}}</span>
                <br>

              </div>

          </div>

        <ul>

</ul>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its just a small mistake which happens very often. Wherever you have given the url to add the item in the cart in your template just put a slash behind the url like this:-

```
<a href="/add/<item-id>/">
```

Comment: Have added slash still getting error. I have uploaded error image in my question pls check it.

Comment: @tanujasahu please share the code of the template where you have written the url.

Comment: Have shared item_detail.html please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "^" from your `path`. You don't need it, since it's not a regular expression. (By the way, "^" in regular expression means "not", i.e. do not match it). So your `path` should simply be:

```
path('add/<int:id>/', views.add_to_cart1, name="add_to_cart1"),
```

Comment: Please share your template

Comment: have shared item_detail.html please check it.